# Transfer column name to template python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to implement a new gadget to my Project, but I don't know if it's realistic to implement.
I am loading a data frame with Pandas. My Code just need four specific columns of a data frame.

Let's define them as, w, x, y, z. Each data frame I want to load has those columns, but it could be that names of columns are different. Like l, m, n, o.

What i now want to implement is, that my program shows every column name and the user has to define them as w,x,y,z. My first idea was, to give each row name of the dataset which i want to load a variable and put those into a list. After that, I can print the list with variable names in console.

After that, the user will be asked which of the variables should be w,x,y,z.

Is there any library for my problem? I could do it by hand, but a library would be the easiest way.

Tim

Comment: I do not think there is such a library. You have to consider if to use CLI or GUI.

Comment: Are there any hints in the Dataframes that would help automate this task (type, distribution)? How many frames are there and do you have some examples? Is it something you are trying to crowdsource?